# Reading and writing VFP (9) files

Tags: visual-foxpro

Is there any library that will let me read/write to VFP 9 files (Visual Fox Pro 9). I have found a few that will let me read/write VFP6 files, but not VFP9.

The language doesn't really matter, as far as I can run it on Linux. (so, no MS IDEs/libs)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you an alternative ODBC driver: http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver